# frequency divider by 42 with 50% duty cycle

Tags: frequency, clock, flipflop, counter

I want to design a clock divider by 42 from flip flops. Is there a way to do that while still gets 50% duty cycle?

Comment: You can use a programmable divider to get a ratio of 21 and then apply that output to a flip-flop to give a final ratio of 42 with a 50% duty cycle.

Comment: Thanks. I can't use microcontroller here. Just basic flip flops because I need a simple and integrated.

Comment: Does the original clock pulse have a 50% duty cycle? Do you want/need to use a specific kind of flip flop (SR, JK, D, T, etc)?

Comment: Yes, my original clock already has a 50% duty cycle. And any kinds of flip flop are OK but I think it may be easier to use D flip flop.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking how to do this with **only** flip-flops this can be done with 21 flip-flops in a Johnson counter arrangement. The output will be high for 21 cycles and low for 21 cycles thus achieving a divide by 42 with 50% duty cycle

[image: divide-by-42]

Comment: Thanks. That is great. Is there a way to reduce the number of flip flops?

Comment: No, a Johnson counter needs N/2 FlipFlops. Counter chaining is not possible, because you can't devide 21 any further by 2.

Comment: How about using 6 D flip flops to get f/21 and then the final JK flip flop to get f/42 with a 50% duty cycle?

Answer (score 0):

6 JK flip-flops and an OR gate.

÷7 ÷3 ÷2 = ÷42

[÷ 42 Java simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+2+0.000005+13.097415321081861+50+5+50%0A156+88+248+144+248+0+0%0A156+208+248+240+248+0+0%0A156+336+248+368+248+0+0%0Aw+328+312+336+312+0%0Aw+328+312+328+248+0%0Aw+328+248+336+248+0%0Aw+72+208+72+312+0%0AR+80+336+24+336+1+2+200+2.5+2.5+0+0.5%0Aw+80+280+80+336+0%0Aw+80+336+200+336+0%0Aw+200+336+200+280+0%0Aw+304+248+304+280+0%0Aw+304+280+336+280+0%0AR+328+248+328+216+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+192+312+192+248+0%0Aw+200+208+72+208+0%0Aw+304+216+264+216+0%0Aw+264+200+432+200+0%0Aw+304+216+304+248+0%0Aw+432+200+432+248+0%0A152+264+208+200+208+1+2+0+5%0AR+88+248+32+248+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+208+248+192+248+0%0Aw+208+280+200+280+0%0Aw+208+312+192+312+0%0Aw+88+312+72+312+0%0Aw+192+248+184+248+0%0Aw+80+280+88+280+0%0Ax+227+369+271+372+4+32+%C3%B7%5Cs7%0A156+464+248+488+248+0+0%0A156+592+248+696+248+0+0%0A156+720+248+792+248+0+0%0Aw+560+248+592+248+0%0Aw+720+280+704+280+0%0Aw+704+280+704+248+0%0Aw+704+248+688+248+0%0Aw+464+280+432+280+0%0Aw+432+280+432+248+0%0Aw+720+312+712+312+0%0Aw+712+312+712+248+0%0Aw+720+248+712+248+0%0AR+712+248+712+216+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+464+248+456+248+0%0AR+456+248+456+216+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+592+280+576+280+0%0Aw+432+200+576+200+0%0Aw+576+200+576+280+0%0Aw+464+312+456+312+0%0Aw+456+312+456+336+0%0Aw+592+312+584+312+0%0Aw+584+312+584+336+0%0Aw+456+336+584+336+0%0Aw+584+336+704+336+0%0Aw+704+336+704+280+0%0Aw+816+248+840+248+0%0Ax+551+371+595+374+4+32+%C3%B7%5Cs3%0Ax+739+367+783+370+4+32+%C3%B7%5Cs2%0Ao+54+64+0+4103+5+0.00009765625+0+2+54+3%0Ao+7+64+0+4103+5+0.00009765625+0+1%0A)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzCVjT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>